# Are java files supported by Objective-C's NSBundle pathForResource method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to obtain the path for a java file which I want to load into an NSString.

Currently this line of code is returning nil.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LockDialog" ofType:@"java"]];
```

I added my file "LockDialog.java" to the project via the menu, File>New>New File. The pathForResource method seems fine for returning the path of txt files or html files but completely fails when I'm trying to get the path of a java file.

Any help or insight massively appreciated,

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding the file to the project, you need to make sure that it gets added to the output bundle.

Open the project in Xcode, navigate to your target, switch to the "Build Phases" tab, and add "LockDialog.java" to the "Copy Bundle Resources" list.

Answer (score 3):

File type should not matter, but chances are the file is not actually being copied to your application bundle. Check your Target>Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources settings to ensure it's there, and if not, drag it over to this list.